# using jQuery zoom to have images pop out

Tags: jquery

I am having a requirement like as per in the site [ticketerasers](http://www.ticketerasers.com/).

There we can see it is a Flash object on the page. I would like to achieve the same using jQuery zoom effect.

How can I arrange the images and implement this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: [hover image zoom with jquery](http://superdit.com/2011/06/11/hover-image-zoom-with-jquery/)